# How can I differentiate this equation? $\sin(x)^{\cos{y}}+\sin{y}^{\cos{x}}=3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\sin(x)^{\cos{y}}+\sin{y}^{\cos{x}}=3$$

I solved a similar equation where those 2 functions were equal to each other by taking the natural log for both sides but now I don't know what to do, taking the natural log of 3 is fine but on the left hand side I can't go any further

Comment: If you want to differentiate $f(x)^{g(x)}$ rewrite it as $\exp(g(x) \cdot \ln\left(f(x)\right))$. Then use the chain rule. In this case the two function are not both functions of $x$, but with the another application of the chain rule you can get the result.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know this rule existed edit: wow it doesn't only work for functions e^2+ln2 = 4